Cursor-ai editor code command not working on Arch Linux
The APPIMAGE file is not working with these errors and it does not allow to install code command or other when it is run:
❯ ./Downloads/cursor-0.32.1x86_64.AppImage
[9512:0416/165640.500124:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(577)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.FileChooser”
[9512:0416/165640.500162:ERROR:select_file_dialog_linux_portal.cc(280)] Failed to read portal version property
[main 2024-04-16T10:56:41.021Z] update#setState disabled
[main 2024-04-16T10:56:41.028Z] update#ctor - updates are disabled as there is no update URL
[main 2024-04-16T10:56:41.091Z] [storage state.vscdb] error checking size of src.vs.platform.reactivestorage.browser.reactiveStorageServiceImpl.persistentStorage.workspaceUser: Error: Unexpected number of rows - 0
[main 2024-04-16T10:56:41.091Z] [storage state.vscdb] error checking size of workbench.panel.aichat.view.aichat.chatdata: Error: Unexpected number of rows - 0
[main 2024-04-16T10:56:41.093Z] [uncaught exception in main]: Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
[main 2024-04-16T10:56:41.093Z] Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
[main 2024-04-16T10:56:42.170Z] [storage state.vscdb] error checking size of workbench.panel.aichat.view.aichat.chatdata: Error: Unexpected number of rows - 0
^C[main 2024-04-16T10:57:16.026Z] Extension host with pid 9819 exited with code: 0, signal: unknown.



Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What are you trying to do? What is that image showing? How is it relevant? That looks like the output you get if you launch the application. Did you see this on your machine? So it does launch? What is cursor-0.32.1x86_64.AppImage? Where did you get it from?

@terdon I cannot install either of  "code" command or "cursor" and the .AppImage was downloaded from their webpage link.

Please EDIT the answers into your question. What happens if you click on "Continue"? I suspect that "install code command" just means adding a line to your bashrc or maybe copying an executable to /usr/bin and that's all that is failing. I mean, you can still launch it manually probably. I tried on my Arch yesterday and I couldn't reproduce this, so there is something specific to your system here.

have you tried the aur package? https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cursor-appimage

@killertofus no I didn't use it from aur. I've downloaded it from "cursor.sh" webpage.

@faisal-ahmed-moshiur try the aur package

@killertofus yes I am using it now.
